# How to reset user login status when program crash

Tags: security, vb6

I'm in the process of securing my program based on user login.
Now I'm only allowed one user to login my program once (it look like Windows Live MSN). If detected same userName that already logged in, it will prompt message to inform user that "You have already logged in".

With this setting, I have met a problem if the program has crashed (which means the user has not yet logged out), how can I auto-reset the user_Status to 0 for this case? So that, he can login after restart the program.

Otherwise, user_Status is 1 and may not allow user to login again.

What is the best way I can solve my problem?

p/s: user_Status = 1 is still login;
     user_Status = 0 is still logout

user_Status is stored in database.

Comment: Q: Is this really VB6?  Q: Where is "user_status" being stored?  Q: What exactly do you mean by "security rule"?  These questions are essential to understanding how to reset it :)

Comment: I'm using VB6 to write my program. "Security rule" means I set the rule to prevent user to login twice. Hope you can understand my question. Thanks.

Comment: paulsm4, you are right. I also would like to know how to detect whether user does not logged out is because of program crash.

Comment: A: you have VB6 program, and you're storing "user_status" in some database.  SUGGESTION: why not store "time" in user_status, and periodically update it from your VB program.  If you update "time" say, every 5 minutes ... and the last update was an hour ago ... perhaps that might be "good enough" to detect a stale (or crashed) login.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Let's say, I set the update "time" for user_Status, every 5 minutes... Q: Does it means that every 5 minutes, the program will update the user_Status?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm suggesting.  That makes it easy to query for any "stale logins" - any login that exceeds some threshold (e.g. 15 minutes, 1 hour, 1 day: whatever you decide).  IMHO...

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you have a client/server parts. If so, create a function to ping a user from server on login if user is already logged in.

Scenario 1:
User 1 is logged in and active. User 2 tries to log in with User 1 credentials. Server will ping User 1 and gets an active response. User 2 gets a message "You have already logged in"

Scenario 2:
User 1 is logged in and then crashes. User 1 restarts and tries to log in again. Server sends a ping to User 1, but gets no response then server allows login.

This way you don't need to have a timer and user's don't need to wait 5 minutes before able to login again.